# Why does my goldfish have red under their chin, like a graze?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, goldfish

I've been lumped with caring for the office goldfish tank. Trying to do my best, I've cared for tropicals before.

One of the goldfish in the tank, my favourite, has recently started developing a rather unpleasant red "graze" underneath their chin. I noticed they would sometimes go in the corner of the tank, and sort of "hang out", nestling their head in the corner and not moving, pointing slightly down, like napping or resting.

I had a suspicion this was a stress related behaviour, and the redness was a product of the rough gravel. I did a 50% water change and that seemed to help for a while, the graze cleared up.

Now, it's just a week later, and the graze is back. The other fish are in *perfect* health. Only this one has trouble. If it's any import, they're also missing a tail (how we got 'em). Good ol' Stumpy.

I noticed today that they were actually sort of "plucking" at the gravel in the corner. Rather than resting their now, they were almost trying to eat the gross stuff at the bottom of the tank, grabbing at the gravel with their mouth.

I guess the question is; is the graze caused *by* the gravel, or is the graze from something else, and the fish is using the gravel to "scratch"?

Appreciate any insight folks can give me. Please help me help my dumb favourite fish.